# Code Igniter Active Record Query doesn't distinguish capital and small alphabets

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hi I created a login System with CI.
Today during a test session I realize that CI doesnot distinguish between Capital and small alphabets.
My login password is **azam123**. but if i enter **AZAM123** , I successfully logged into system.
I am pasting my MODEL CODE here plz help me don't know how to solve this issue.
I googled alot but didn't find answer.

```
<?php

class Login_user extends CI_Model
{
    public function authenticate_user($username,$password)
    {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);


        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using? In MySQL for example, non-binary string comparisons are case insensitive by default (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html).
I should also add that you shouldn't store the password in the database, you should store a hash. Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: lets forget to store hash.

Comment: plz tell me how to overcome this problem?

Comment: The mysql documentation link I sent you contains all the information you need. Use a binary column type or a binary collation.